# How to get realtime coordinates with React DnD

Tags: javascript, reactjs, drag-and-drop, draggable, react-dnd

`react-dnd` library for ReactJS provides `begin` and `end` callbacks for dragging. However, I can't find a way in the docs to access the `drag` event that fires while a drag is in progress. What would be the correct way to access this event in a component that uses `react-dnd`?

I want real time feedback so I can display the coordinates of a drag in progress.

Expected:

```js
function Draggable({ onDrag, children }) {
  const [, drag] = useDrag({
    item: { id, type },
    onDrag, // this is not available in react-dnd
  })

  return <div ref={drag}>{children}</div>
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get realtime coordinates through DragLayerMonitor.

Check the document [DragLayerMonitor](https://react-dnd.github.io/react-dnd/docs/api/drag-layer-monitor) and the [custom drag layer example](https://react-dnd.github.io/react-dnd/examples/drag-around/custom-drag-layer).

I've made a slider component in this way and it works well for me. I made it a codepen, but I don't know how to post codepen link here. Anyway, I believe you will figure it out, that [custom drag layer example](https://react-dnd.github.io/react-dnd/examples/drag-around/custom-drag-layer) helped me a lot.